# problem when run rails db:setup : schema.rb doesn't exist yet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am newbie with Rails and having this problem.

I created a rails folder named freelancer. Everthing seems ok.

Then, I went to this folder and ran this cmd :

```
rails db:setup
```

It said to me this error : `/freelancer/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run rails db*migrate to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you should instead alter /home/anh/Desktop/freelancer/config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that will be loaded`

Then I ran this command as they said

```
rails db:migrate
```

Then I ran the command `rails db:setup`, they said to me that

```
Database 'bai9freelancer_development' already exists
Database 'bai9freelancer_test' already exists
```

I am very confusing because those problem. First, when I create my rails folder freelancer, no problem. Why schema.rb doesn't exist ? Second, They said to me that I must run rails db:migrate then try rails db:setup again, then they said to me that already exists. That why ? Could you please explain those problem for me ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

When you ran

```
rails db:migrate
```

you already created db/schema.rb

Running `rails db:setup` is the equivalent of

```
rails db:create
rails db:migrate
rails db:seed
```

So after you ran `rails db:migrate` you don't need to recall `rails db:setup` anymore. You can find out more in the [documentation here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)